# routes.MapRoute Customisation : The incoming request does not match any route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am new to MVC: and get the error " The incoming request does not match any route"

The controller controllerWorkflowTestController.cs has code:

```
public class WorkFlowTestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult openSampleView(Models.WorkFlowTest  model)
    {

        if (model.SubmissionId  != null)
        {
            return View("Submission");
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

Model has code:

```
   namespace MockBDPWorkflowTestApp.Models

   {

           public class WorkFlowTest

           {
             public string SubmissionId { get; set; }

           }
  }
```

}

and in global .asax I have :

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
       "Default",
       "WorkFlowTest/openSampleView/&SubmissionId=1",
       new { controller = "WorkFlowTest", action = "openSampleView", id = "" }
       );

    }
```

This gives error The incoming request does not match any route. This looks simple but no experience on customizing routes in MVC. I just need url which passes parameter for my action "openSampleView" ,  so that it accepts the parameter value and renders the view. I have used model for parameter  but any suggestions to correct this is appreciated , Thanks.

Comment: What request you are trying to evaluate through your MVC app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass SubmissionId in the url you will need that as a parameter for the action, rather than the model. Use model as a parameter when POSTing data from a view. Also, if you want to use the model in the view you'll need to pass it in.

So that gives a controller action of

```
public ActionResult openSampleView(string submissionId)
{
    if (submissionId == null) return null;
    var model = new Models.WorkFlowTest {SubmissionId = submissionId};
    return View("Submission", model);
}
```

In your route you can then define whatever url you want while passing in the submissionId. An example would be:

```
routes.MapRoute("Submission", "submissions/{submissionId}", new { controller = "WorkFlowTest", Action = "openSampleView" });
```

Then the URL http://www.example.com/submissions/1 should work for submission with id of 1 (replacing www.example.com with your site obviously).

To use the submission id in the View you'll need to bind the view to the model with the following line at the start of the view.

```
@model MockBDPWorkflowTestApp.Models.WorkFlowTest
```

Then within the view you can retrieve the id with

```
@Model.SubmissionId
```